# Do I need Customs clearance to fly an N-registered aircraft from Italy to Switzerland?

Tags: air-traffic-control, international

I need to fly from Italy to Switzerland in my aircraft with N markings.
I've been told I need a clearance from a customs office within an airport prior to crossing the border. Is this true?

Answer (score 4):

It's true. You need to take off from a authorised Airport with customs in Italy and land at an airport with customs in Switzerland as your first stop.

Here is all information you need including a list of airports with customs. 
https://www.ezv.admin.ch/ezv/en/home/information-private/waren-anmelden/einfuhr-in-die-schweiz/warenanmeldung/grenzueberschreitende-fluege.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not to do with the N-markings... ANY aircraft that wants to fly between Italy and Switzerland needs to fly between 'Customs airfields'. Note - you don't need *permission* from Customs, just to leave and enter via a Customs airfield, reporting to Customs at those airfields.